# Django: check on model with manytomany field if object is in that list with filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter, django-annotate

Let's say we have a `Notification` model with `manytomany=ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)` field with `User` model.
How to annotate a field `is_in_manytomany` to return boolean with True and False only depending on a condition, whether `self.request.user` is in `Notification` `ManyToMany` field or not. This code below returns weird `True` and `False` and also `None`, regardless of the default value of `BooleanField`.

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)

qs = Notification.objects.all().annotate(
                is_in_manytomany =ExpressionWrapper(
                    Q(manytomany__in = [user]),
                    output_field=BooleanField(default=True)
                )
            )

for item in qs:
    print(item.is_in_manytomany)
```

What am I doing wrong? How do you get a True/False annotation on the given condition?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I hope this helps someone else:
We need to put Q | Q in Q to achieve the results

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)

qs = Notification.objects.all().annotate(
                is_in_manytomany=ExpressionWrapper(
                    Q(Q(manytomany=user)| Q(manytomany=None)),
                    output_field=BooleanField()
                )
            )

for item in qs:
    print(item.is_in_manytomany)
```

Explanation: we did not need to do `manytomany__in=[user]`, because its a `ManyToMany` field; `manytomany=user` is enough, since some objects have `manytomany=None` (because in my case the `manytomany=ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)`, we need to add the second `Q(manytomany=None)`. Also to reverse the boolean we can add `~` to any `Q` expression.